# No response after submitting the homework in the job interview process

Tags: interviewing

During the first round of interviews, the company asked me to submit a design project. They gave me 2 weeks so, I submitted my work through email.

As soon as I submitted my work, they replied back to me they will be out of the  country for a business trip and get back to me when they come back.

2 week passed, I contacted to them via email to follow up if they reviewed my work, and I haven't heard back from them.

Should I keep follow up with them? or just forget about this job?

Comment: If they don't respond to e-mail, it's legitimate to pick up the phone and ask for confirmation that they received it and an estimate of when the decision might be made.  But silence often means you simply didn't get the job; proceed on that assumption. (Whether they cheated you out of work or it was a legitimate skill test is something we really can't answer from here, though many have opinions in the topic.)

Comment: Have you tried calling them on the phone?

Comment: "they replied back to me they will be out of the country for a business trip" - what, the whole company?

Answer (score 13):

I am afraid that what is more likely is they have been avoiding you as soon as they got what they wanted.

This is a more than a known way to get work done for free by less reputable companies with false "interview" processes. In my home country, this scam is quite frequent with "interviews", "proofs of concept" and "competitions" for design work.

Showing a portfolio or doing a work of several minutes may very well be an interview task; a design work of a couple of days, is anything but.

Consider this a life learning experience and move on. Do not let yourself let be tricked into working for free next time.

Comment: And consider writing a Glassdoor review of them, mentioning that they crowdsource work through interviews.

Comment: @JaguarWong The advice is not the best one, especially if not anonymous; beware of libel laws.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - Agreed.  You need to be able to prove your "homework" was used in production, or at least in a product demo.

Comment: A better idea is writing in Glassor thr facts "I was asked a design project of 2 weeks in an interview and was not hired". I suspect there will be others.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely still try to follow up, and I recommend you to do it soon.

If you have a phone number for your interviewer, call that and leave a message if you have to. If you don't have a direct number, call the company's front desk and ask to be connected to the person you interviewed with.

It could be as simple as your email being buried somewhere or they are too busy that they have forgotten about reviewing your work, particularly if they have a lot to catch up on after traveling.